# How do I build a glycosylated protein from PDB files manually?

Tags: protein-structure, pymol, modelling

I have a large protein PDB file (~3500 residues) and a couple of PDB files containing glycan structures I sourced from GLYCAM.

How can I attach the N and O-glycans onto each protein residue with software? In PyMol, I am stuck at loading up the protein PDB file and glycan file together, but I don't know how to put the two elements together. Are there any commands I can use? or tutorial resources I can take a look at? I'm open to trying other platforms.

I've tried glycan modelling webtools (GLYCAM, CHARMM-GUI) but they can't seem to process my large glycoprotein - leading to errors or extended waiting times which also end in failure.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ChimeraX](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/).

1. Open your glycans and your protein pdb files as different models, then move the models of your glycans until they are near the residues you want (in the Toolbar: [Right Mouse](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/tools/mousemodes.html) -> Move Model).
2. Then use [`combine`](https://www.rbvi.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/commands/combine.html) to combine one of your glycan model with the protein
3. Finally Use Tools -> Structure Editing -> Build Structure and its [Adjust Bonds](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimerax/docs/user/tools/buildstructure.html#bonds) menu to add covalent bonds. You can also add or delete atoms this way.

This is a straightforward but complicated and tedious way of doing this, and it will give you unideal structures. There should be an equivalent way to proceed using PyMol. For a more automatized way I can only recommend having a look at [PyRosetta](https://www.pyrosetta.org/). There is a [Jupyter Notebook tutorial about adding glycosylation](https://nbviewer.org/github/RosettaCommons/PyRosetta.notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/13.02-Glycan-Modeling-and-Design.ipynb).

There may be other tools out there for doing this, like [MoleculeKit](https://software.acellera.com/docs/stable/moleculekit/index.html), but I'm less aware of them. A nasty solution would be to cut your protein in smaller pieces, glycosylate each part with CHARMM-GUI, then reassemble them.

Answer (score 1):

*answer from @coot, converted from comments (please edit this answer to improve it if you can):*

Manual model building is a common thing in structural biology. Usually, Coot is used.